# Entity extraction web services

Tags: named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction

Are there any paid or free named entity recognition web services available.

Basically I'm looking for something - where if I pass a text like:

> "John had french fries at Burger King"

It should be identify - something along the lines:

> Person: John
>
> Organization: Burger King

I've heard of [Annie from GATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Architecture_for_Text_Engineering) - but I don't think it has a web service available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[OpenCalais](http://viewer.opencalais.com/) by Reuters - pretty awesome at detecting companies, political entities etc. but not, say, food items.

[image]

Free for 50,000 requests per day even for commercial, [as long as you display their logo](http://www.opencalais.com/APIKey).

Totally tripped by certain types of input though. As of now, this results in nothing being detected, despite [Wacom being a relatively well-known company](https://www.google.com/finance?q=OTCMKTS%3AWACMY).

> Wacom introduces WILL - the Wacom Ink Layer Language as a Leading Standard in Digital Inking

Answer (score 3):

[DBPedia Spotlight](http://dbpedia.org/spotlight) was just released yesterday. Its based on Wikipedia articles and also available as Open Source.

Answer (score 3):

[Alchemy API](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/entity) also offers a web API with some rich functionality.  It includes named entity recognition as well as sentiment analysis, concept tagging, and several other NLP-related features.

Free for 1k queries per day, then with various tiers of paid subscriptions if you need more than that.

Comment: Exactly what i needed. How can i get the apikey?

Comment: There's a link from the home page to a [registration form](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/register.html), looks like you can get one there

Answer (score 2):

[Rosoka Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00E6FGJZ0) is available through Amazon AWS Marketplace. You can stand it up and use it for as long as you need it and shut it down when you are done. You can use the drag and drop feature if you only need to process a handful of documents, or use the webservice interfaces if you want to do bulk processing. It is inexpensive option for using commercial grad entity extraction for short periods.
support 230 different languages.